# Algorithm for Graph in edge time - can there be only one source?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, networkx

I have been given a [Tournament graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)).

Now my question is: does the graph have only one source and only one sink? I don't know why that is in fact and how I can find those.

Also, I should create an algorithm to find the source in O(|E|) time. My approach was like to decide between Edmons-Karp or Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm and only use one iterative. Is that correct or what should be done to find the source in O(E) time?

Comment: Turniergraph = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory) in English

Comment: Also, from what I read while looking at the Tournaments, the single source happens only in the case when the graph is acyclic. This question might be better suited for CS stackexchange: [similar discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875287/proving-if-v-a-is-a-tournament-then-v-a-has-a-unique-complete-simple-path).